# Different Representation of Linear System

Tags: linear-algebra

Currently working on my Linear Algebra homework and I have come across several problems of the same form that I haven't the slightest clue how to approach.  Keep in mind I haven't taken math classes for some time now, so I am a bit rusty.  I have searched online, and in my book, to no avail.

I certainly don't want anyone to do the problem for me, just (1) what problems of these forms are called - e.g. so I can search on google for info on how to solve it; and (2) maybe some links for where I can get more information.

Sorry for such a stupid post, but I am running short on time, and was hoping someone might be able to help.

One of the problems I'm referring to:

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is a specific name for the particular problem other than linear systems. You might want to look up reduced row forms, intersection of planes, finding null space, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case here you have the equations of two planes (in coordinate form). Now you have to get the equation of the intersecting line (parameter form).

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Would be nice if our prof mentioned the different forms before assigning homework.

Answer (score -1):

Note that you can write the equations in the form
$A \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 9 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix} -\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ -3 \end{bmatrix} x_3$, so we get
$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} = A^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} 9 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix} -A^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ -3 \end{bmatrix} x_3$.

In the question you can take $x_3 = s$.

Comment: Why the downvote?